# Regex to match either one of two filename patterns

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I am trying to match filenames using `boost::regex` and I have two kinds of patters:

1. `XYZsomestring`
2. `XYsomestringENDING`

The string `somestring` can be anything (>0 characters).
The beginning of the filename is either `XYZ` or `XY`. 
If it is `XY` , there has to be the string `ENDING` that terminates the whole sequence.
I tried to combine two regex with `|` but it doesnt work.
This matches filenames with the first pattern:

```
(XYZ)(.*)
```

and this matches filenames with the second pattern:

```
(XY)(.*)(ENDING)
```

But when I combine them, only the first pattern matches:

```
((XYZ)(.*))|((XY)(.*)(ENDING))
```

All this is supposed to be case insensitive, that is why I use `boost::regex::icase` in the constructor.
I have tried it without that `icase`, doesnt work either).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give some particular examples that do and do not match? And better small code that demonstrates the problem, because the regexp itself seems correct.

Comment: @tzippy , string  "XYZENDING" should give a coincidence?

Comment: Try `((XY)(.*)(ENDING))|((XYZ)(.*))`

Comment: @stribizhev , not. On string XYZ does not give the true result. Probably better to use + instead of *

Answer (score 1):

There may be simpler expressions but I think the regex `^xy(?(?!z).*ending$|.*$)` should do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

bool bmatch(const std::string& x, const std::string& re_) {
  const boost::regex re(re_, boost::regex::icase);
  boost::smatch what;
  return boost::regex_match(x, what, re);
}

int main()
{
  std::string re = "^xy(?(?!z).*ending$|.*$)";
  std::vector<std::string> vx = { "XYZ124f5sf", "xyz12345",
                                  "XY38fsj dfENDING", "xy4 dfhd ending",
                                  "XYZ", "XY345kENDI", "xy56NDING" };
  for (auto i : vx) {
    std::cout << "\nString '" << i;
    if (bmatch(i, re)) {
      std::cout <<
        "' was matched." << std::endl;
     } else {
      std::cout <<
        "' was not matched." << std::endl;
     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here's a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b67bd4700a2f0544).

**Edit:** 
Additionally, I think the regex `^xy(z.*|.*ending)$` should work as well.